# What crypto random generator C code could use on WP8.1?

Tags: c++, c, windows, random, windows-runtime

I've taken some C code and compiled it inside a C++ WinRT Component for Universal Apps. I then wrote a C++ wrapper class to expose the functionality of C code to my C# Universal Store Project as per the manuals: [1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh755833.aspx), [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh755822.aspx).

Works fine for Windows 8.1 part of the project, but fails to load the component on Windows Phone 8.1 saying just `"The specified module could not be found"`. I've found out that the problem is that the C code uses the following random generator function:

```
# define RtlGenRandom SystemFunction036
# if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C"
# endif
BOOLEAN NTAPI RtlGenRandom(PVOID RandomBuffer, ULONG RandomBufferLength);
# pragma comment(lib, "advapi32.lib")
```

Which seems to be unavailable on WP8.1.

[This MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387694%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) suggests that we should use `CryptGenRandom` instead, but the latter resides in `Wincrypt.h`, which is not available on WP8.1.

So, what random generator can we use **from C code**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted something that would not involve calling C++/CX code from C, but found nothing so far. So, below is the solution I use for now.

```
// C++/CX

using namespace Platform;
using namespace Windows::Security::Cryptography;
using namespace Windows::Storage::Streams;

extern "C" void GenerateRandomBytes(unsigned char *bytes, unsigned int length)
{
    IBuffer^ buffer = CryptographicBuffer::GenerateRandom(length);
    DataReader^ reader = DataReader::FromBuffer(buffer);
    reader->ReadBytes(ArrayReference<unsigned char>(bytes, buffer->Length));
}

// C

#ifdef RtlGenRandom
RtlGenRandom((PVOID) buf, (ULONG) size);
#else
GenerateRandomBytes((unsigned char*)buf, (unsigned int)size);
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Use WinRT Windows::Security::Cryptography [C++] API .
[CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.security.cryptography.cryptographicbuffer.generaterandom.aspx) will do the required

Comment: I need to call it **from C code**, not from C++ wrapper class.

Comment: Can you tweak the C code to call a method from the C++ wrapper?  How about a small new C++ routine specifically for that purpose?  That would give you a back door.

Comment: I ended up doing that, actually. And I don't like it. It made me modify the code of the library in a way that is unlikely to make it to the repository. So, I'm looking for a way to get things done in C. @rossum